# How do I reduce chrome's CPU and memory usage on page load?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-extensions, tampermonkey

I am running a Tampermonkey script in Chrome that auto-refreshes every 4-8 seconds a page within a page range that looks for changes in the HTML elements and acts within a certain threshold.

The script itself works without a hitch, and I think it will continue to work for what I need. The problem is my computer runs quite slowly and choppily when I try to run this script in parallel fifteen to twenty times. I want to run more in parallel but I don't want to reduce how often the page loads because that reduces the effectiveness of the script.

I think my best bet is if I can not render the page, all without breaking the script. I don't need to see the page when it loads each time, so if I can altogether stop the page renders and have the script run on the HTML alone, that'd be great.

That said, I am open to other solutions instead or in addition to help me.

Comment: Have you looked at how parts of Chrome are using the memory using the built in information page?

Comment: how do I check this?

Comment: click the `settings menu` in the browser and select `View background pages`

Comment: http://imgur.com/RkdQQUd

Comment: Since you just want to check the HTML, don't refresh the page. Use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to fetch the page and compare the results.  This will be vastly faster, but won't always work on AJAX-driven pages.